# How can I split to firefox full screen with awesome window manager

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell

I am using awesome window manager and ubuntu 20.04.

When I set firefox to full screen (F11 button), the screen is split, but it becomes one screen.

I want to split firefox into top and bottom full screen.

How can I do this?

I tried to set "fullscreen true" in "rc.lua", but it didn't work.

■.config/awesome/rc.lua

```
awful.rules.rules = {
    -- All clients will match this rule.
    { rule = { },
      properties = { border_width = beautiful.border_width,
                     border_color = beautiful.border_normal,
                     fullscreen = true,
```